# error installing caffe

Tags: macos, unix, boost, caffe

I am trying to install caffe on my mac. I have installed boost but I get this error:

```
make pycaffe -j8
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: library not found for -lboost_thread-mt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

Comment: How did you install Boost? Did you compile it by yourself or took pre compiled binaries? In your Boost installation location, under stage directory, what is the convention for the libraries there? (for example, libboost_atomic-vc110-mt-s-1_58). Can you copy please one library name and comment here?

Answer (score 5):

You have probably installed boost without boost-thread, or have old installer that installed boost_thread-mt as boost_thread. If it's the second then you can just make symbolic link from `libboost_thread.a` to `libboost_thread-mt.a`.

If it's the first cause, then you have to reinstall brew with boost-thread, and the easiest way will be to [get Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and install boost with it:

```bash
brew install boost
```

Which installs proper libs:

```
-> % ls  /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.* 
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a     /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using anaconda, you can also provide the boost dependency using the conda-forge anaconda channel:

`$ conda install -c conda-forge boost`

And create the symlinks, as @Marqin said, if they're not available.

The conda-forge boost might soon include the `-mt` libraries. I opened an issue for it on [their github repo](https://github.com/conda-forge/boost-cpp-feedstock/issues/18).